# VB.net total sum from a csv file

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have CSV file that contains some values. It's looks like this:

```
1;11,19;91,69
1;2,8  ;26,54
2;0    ;2,79
2;7,8  ;0
3;0    ;35,44
1;0    ;8,89
2;27,33;16,5
3;0    ;35,49
2;0    ;42,69
2;0    ;93,09
```

I need to write new strings to new CSV which contains sums of columns 1 and 2 sorted by column 0. It have to looks like this:

```
1;13,99;127,12
2;35,13;155,07
3;0    ;70,93
```

At the start I tried to calculate sums of columns, but even there I got a problem and can't figure out how I have to do this. And I am to far of my target with sorting by values of column 0. Now my code looks like this.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim file As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("path\input.csv")
        Dim sum As Decimal
        sum = 0
        Dim sb As New List(Of String)
        For Each line In file
            Dim col = line.Split(";"c)
            Dim result As Decimal = sum + col(1)
            Dim result1 As Decimal = sum + col(2)
            sb.Add(String.Join(";", col(0) & ";" & result & ";" & result1))
        Next
        IO.File.WriteAllLines("path\output.csv", sb.ToArray())
    End Sub
```

I seen the same question with answers for Python, but I have no idea how to transform code to VB.Net.
EDIT: Have to say, that numbers in column 0 are just examples and there are more then 50 unique values.

Comment: "1;13,99;127,12" <- how did you get to '99' ?

Comment: You know that's not a CSV file, right?

Comment: I have delimiter ; not a comma. 13,99 is result of values 11,19+2,80 in first two strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, actually you don't need to **sort** the entries, you should **Group** them by the first column and sum the second and third ones of each group.

Here's another solution:

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Globalization

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim inputFile = "path/input.csv"
    Dim outputFile = "path/output.csv"
    Dim ci = New CultureInfo("de-DE")

    File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, File.ReadLines(inputFile).
                        Select(Function(x) x.Split(";"c)).
                        GroupBy(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x(0))).
                        Select(Function(x)
                                    Return String.Format(
                                    "{0};{1};{2}",
                                    x.Key,
                                    x.Sum(Function(y) Decimal.Parse(y(1), ci)),
                                    x.Sum(Function(y) Decimal.Parse(y(2), ci)))
                                End Function).ToArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, it work! One more question. Actually my csv contains more then 3 columns, only for few of them I need sums, but I want to keep other columns in new csv. How to add them to String.Format?

Comment: @Иван Олександров You are welcome. You can add more place holders in the `String.Format` method: `{0};{1};{2};{3};{N}` and set their values as you see above. So after the last `x.Sum(..)` you can add more values separated by commas using the `Select` method like: `x.Select(Function(y) y(3)) : x.Select(Function(y) y(4))` and so on.

Comment: Yes! I got it work with First celection x.Select(Function(y) y(3)).First, and so on

Answer (score 2):

This should get you fairly close:

```
Dim result = _
    lines _
        .Select(Function(x) x.Split(";"c)) _
        .Select(Function(x) New With _
        { _
            .c1 = x(0), _
            .c2 = Decimal.Parse(x(1).Trim(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-de")), _
            .c3 = Decimal.Parse(x(2).Trim(), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-de")) _
        }) _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) x.c1) _
        .Select(Function(x) New With { .c1 = x.Key, .c2 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.c2), .c3 = x.Sum(Function(y) y.c3) }) _
        .ToArray()
```

That gives me the numbers you wanted.

Comment: about two hours I try to get this code work without succes. Declarations are not accepted. "." requared With and With requared End With etc, etc

Comment: @ИванОлександров Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I tried that code in VS2017 in case there was a typo or something, but it worked with no problem for me.

Comment: @ИванОлександров - I test all code before I post it. This works just fine.